# Using Piranha CMS with MVC5 and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication, piranha-cms

Please bear with me, I am fairly new to dealing with authentication.  All our users are on the same domain, and in the old site (Web Forms, VB.NET) I was hiding or displaying items based on whether the user was in a particular role-- manager or IT, for example.

I've just installed and tested Piranha 2.2.5 on the new site with MVC5 and I like its features. It should significantly cut down on the amount of stuff I'm hard-coding for people. (I'm actually appalled we didn't have a CMS yet.) However, I noticed that the piranha manager uses forms authentication. This is fine for the manager pages; there will only be a few people logging in to actually upload content.

But how would I retain the ability, on my layouts and other pages, to detect the Active Directory/Windows user identity? We have hundreds of users with high turnover, it would be time-prohibitive to have them each log in to the intranet with a unique identity. Plus I don't really need any active authentication in terms of logging in for the main site. We are just allowing all our users to see all the pages, and for now not storing any personal information. The managers basically just get some additional menu items.

I've read a bit about trying to separate the Piranha-managed pages into a separate area? Or would I need a separate site? Would I still be able to embed Piranha content pages in my other pages as partial pages if they are in a separate site/project? Sorry if these are very elementary questions. I've searched quite a lot but am still stuck. Maybe it's Friday-brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking it's perfectly doable to configure different authentication settings for different parts of a web application with web.config.

In other words, it should be possible to use Windows auth for the public pages and forms for everything beneath /manager.

The only downside with this will be that the preview functionality won't work as it depends on the public page being previewed can access the forms authenticated manager user.

**EDIT**

And regarding the "home" prefix on URL:s there is a config option called **PrefixlessPermalinks** that removes this

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks for stopping by! Oh yes, you are right I did set up the prefixless permalinks, I misspoke about that. So I should separate my pages into separate areas, right? Any pages that I want under content management should go in the manager area and my other pages can go under home and other custom areas? I'll have to look up exactly how to set that up in web.config but I'm very happy to hear it's possible!

Comment: Also, would this work if I'm embedding the content-managed pages as partial pages into my windows-auth pages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put Piranha into passive mode, there is an entry in the web.config file for this under the  entry. This should allow MVC to do the routing instead of Piranha. (I couldn't access the manager area when I did this but I also didn't spend long looking into why)

You could also look at just using Piranha to manage your users & rework the  Web Forms code from here for MVC http://piranhacms.org/docs/gists/simple-login-form then possibly convert the piranha user into an active directory user?

Code from link:

```
<form method="post" action="@Href("~/account/login")">
  <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="@Href("~/home/mypage")" />
  <input type="hidden" name="failureurl" value="@Href("~/home/mypage?msg=err")" />

  <label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="login" />
  <label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" />

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

From the comments on the same page:

> You can call Piranha.Models.SysUser.LoginUser(..) && Piranha.Models.SysUser.LogoutUser()

Hope that points you in the right direction!

Comment: This might also be of use: http://piranhacms.org/draft/the-magic-of-mvc-routing-with-multiple-areas

Comment: If I put piranha in passive mode I'm not able to get the proper routing. Piranha will put all pages I create through the manager under /home/ which is pretty constricting for my site url design. I wasn't able to find a workaround for that. I also had issues accessing the manager.     I'm not sure I understand your suggestion for just using piranha to manage users? Are you suggesting something like impersonation, so all users would automatically login under the same account?